# Update frame and content of nib programatically

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, xcode5, uilabel, xib

I have a simple nib with a couple of `UILabel`s inside it.

At one scenario I want to add a `UILabel` to the bottom depending on the state of the application. Is it possible to dynamically/programtically add content to a nib and how so?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this from code instead, i.e. the ViewController associated with the .nib.

In the View Controller's class, add a few UILabel instance variables in the header file, i.e.

```
@interface MyVC : UIViewController {
   UILabel* conditionalLabel;
} ...
```

Then, in the .m implementation file,

```
@implementation MyVC : UIViewController {
    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
         if(myConditionToShowLabel) {
            if(!conditionalLabel) {
               conditionalLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
               [self.view addSubView:conditionalLabel];
            } else {
               [conditionalLabel removeFromSuperView];
               [self.view addSubView:conditionalLabel];
            }
        }
     }
```

Remember to set the view controller class to MyVC in the NIB editor in XCode :-)

Something like that would work, and it's entirely normal practice :-) It's hard to make a dynamic user interface with NIBs alone—sometimes you need to get "down to coding".

Answer (score 0):

You can add the UILabel in view programatically. Best place to do this is **viewDidAppear** method.

for example,

```
-(void)viewDidAppear

{

[super viewDidAppear];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.view.frame),     CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.frame)-30, 200, 30)];

[self.view addSubView:label];

}
```

The label will appear at the bottom of view.